# Is the US Department of Defense ip address 6.3.6.0 valid? (reported by Apple products)

Tags: logging, ip-address, iphone, apple, ipad

I've recently seen a lot of this IP address. A [geo ip lookup](http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/6.3.6.0) tells me it is US Department of Defense Network in Arizona so why do some routers ([here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2315014?start=0&tstart=0) and [here](http://forums.dealmac.com/read.php?1,1017756)) default to this address?

The real question is should I treat `6.3.6.0` as an incorrectly reported ip address or not?

I have only anecdotal evidence of this so I wondering if am i missing some inside joke... or maybe the US Department of Defense produces routers and is particularly active :)

Comment: Update: I have thousands of iPhone/Pad/Pods reporting this as their ip address

Comment: What are they reporting that to you with?

Comment: Just one app, and we've concluded it is a bug that they are supplying an IP address in the first place. That is beyond the scope of this question other than to say we aren't actually receiving traffic from 6.3.6.0. The question still remains if IOS/Apple report to this address in any scenario

Comment: Well, apparently [other Apple devices report it as an address on an inactive interface](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA21559) - seems like a bug..  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes that must be the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a legitimate address range - if Apple's using it as a default address for their routers, then they're doing it wrong.

ARIN confirms that the [whole `6.0.0.0/8` range is assigned to "USAISC"](http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-6-0-0-0-1.html), and if you take a look at a BGP [looking glass](http://www.bgp4.as/looking-glasses), you'll see that `6.3.0.0/18` is being actively routed on the internet by [AS668, which is assigned to the US DoD](http://whois.arin.net/rest/asn/AS668/pft).